# TypeError: V is not a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

If you get:

> TypeError: V is not a function

in the console where should you look for errors?
I'm just a student and I have no idea how to fix my webpage. I'm doing an online course and following my teacher's instructions. 
The project is quite big already, with quite a lot of files. I don't really know what part of the project I have to show in order to get some help. Everything was working fine before starting to use **Angular**'s `$resource`.
Is this error indicating at least which part of the project is wrong?
Starting from there I can provide more detailed information.

Comment: You wont get much help here with homework unless you show an effort yourself, but my tip would be to search your code for `V()`.

Comment: Is it possible that you call some method that is called `V` in your project? If so, then make sure that this is a function.

Comment: did you minimize your scripts?  single letter functions are usually most commonly seen in minimized scripts, but there are specific steps you must take to ensure that an angular app is minification safe.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I thought that it was related to $resource so I did some research and found out that there was a conflict between Angular and $resource versions, even tough I used Bower to install everything. I just had to update $resource version.

Comment: If you are experimenting with the framework try *not* to use the min version

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when call angular default methods incorrectly, like I get same error when tried to use validators

totalInvestmentAmt: [null, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.floatNumber, Validators.min(1)]]

Fixed by

totalInvestmentAmt: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(CustomValidators.floatNumber), Validators.min(1)]]

Here in validation no any method with CustomValidators.floatNumber in angular

Answer (score 0):

Ar123 had it right but he didn't explain it well.
If you are having trouble with validation, then you're probably confusing ValidatorOrOpts with ValidatorFn.

ValidatorOrOpts is the second argument of FormControl, and it's an optional object that has the key 'validator' and the value of type ValidatorFn.

If you are using something like a formBuilder, then you just need the ValidatorFn inside your array. which is just a function that takes in the control and outputs the error.

'v is not a function' because angular forms is looping over the list of ValidatorFn and is running them as functions. but you probably didn't give it a function.